# Why when referring to the second field, the value is taken from the first?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently work with jquery. And I have such a question. I add elements to the page via forEach and I need to access the field of a specific product in jquery.

My JQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('.count').on('blur', function getTotalPrice(){
    var name = $('#name').html();
    var count = $('.count').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "cart",
        data: "name=" + name + "&count=" + count,
        success: function(data){
            $("#totalPrice").text("Total price: " + data['totalPrice'].toFixed(2)).wrap("<h4></h4>");
            $("#productCount").text("(" + data['productCount'] + ")");

            $.each([data['cartItems']], function(key, value) {

            });

        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
});
});
```

My Page:

```
<table>
                     <tr>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Category</th>
                        <th>Company Manufacturer</th>
                        <th>QTY</th>
                        <th>Prices</th>
                        <th>Total Prices</th>
                     </tr>

                     <c:forEach items="${cartItems}" var="items">
                        <tr>
                        <td><a href="images/product/${items.key.imageName}"><img src="images/product/${items.key.imageName}" width=100></td>
                        <td><span id="name">${items.key.name}</span></td>
                        <td>${items.key.category.name}</td>
                        <td>${items.key.manufacturer.name}</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="count" value="${items.value}"></td>
                        <td>${items.key.price}</td>
                        <td><span id="totalPriceForOne">${items.key.price * items.value}</span></td>
                        <td><a href="removeItemFromCart?name=${items.key.name}">Remove item</a></td>
                        </tr>
                     </c:forEach>
                </table>

         </div>
             <div align="right" style="color: #0087ff">
                 <span id="totalPrice"><h4>Total price: ${totalPrice}</h4></span>
             </div>

               <div align="right"><a href="order.jsp" class="to-buy">Make order</a></div>
```

My Page when i fill it:

```
<table>
                     <tr>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Category</th>
                        <th>Company Manufacturer</th>
                        <th>QTY</th>
                        <th>Prices</th>
                        <th>Total Prices</th>
                     </tr>


                        <tr>
                        <td><a href="images/product/3.png"><img src="images/product/3.png" width=100></td>
                        <td><span class="name">ALLIANCE_SUNGLASSES</span></td>
                        <td>accessories</td>
                        <td>Luis Vuitton</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="count" value="1"></td> //сюда обращается
                        <td>810.00</td>
                        <td><span id="totalPriceForOne">810.00</span></td>
                        <td><a href="removeItemFromCart?name=ALLIANCE_SUNGLASSES">Remove item</a></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                        <td><a href="images/product/2.png"><img src="images/product/2.png" width=100></td>
                        <td><span class="name">45DAVID</span></td>
                        <td>jeans</td>
                        <td>Collins</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="count" value="12"></td> //сюда обратиться не выходит
                        <td>100.00</td>
                        <td><span id="totalPriceForOne">1200.00</span></td>
                        <td><a href="removeItemFromCart?name=45DAVID">Remove item</a></td>
                        </tr>

                </table>
```

So I have a problem, I want that when I change the values ​​of the count field, they change for that product opposite which this field is located.  Now when I try to change the count in the second product, it refers to the field of the first product, and the values ​​do not change. If I turn to the first field, then everything is fine there, I indicate the quantity of goods I need, and it recounts the price for me. But why do I fail when I try to do this for the second product? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **change this line;** `var count = $('.count').val();` to `var count = $(this).val();`

Since there seems to be many instances of .count, you have to refer to the currently selected element with **$(this)**.

For the name, it's a bit tricky, you have to find the nearest .name. Since the .count is inside a td, you have to **use .parent() to navigate to the td**. Once you're in the td, you have to **use .parent() again to navigate to the tr**. Once in the tr, you need to **use .find(".name") to find the child with class name.**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $('.count').on('blur', function getTotalPrice(){
        // updated
        var name = $(this).parent().parent().find('.name').html();

        // updated
        var count = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "cart",
            data: "name=" + name + "&count=" + count,
            success: function(data){
                $("#totalPrice").text("Total price: " + data['totalPrice'].toFixed(2)).wrap("<h4></h4>");
                $("#productCount").text("(" + data['productCount'] + ")");

                $.each([data['cartItems']], function(key, value) {

                });

            },
            dataType: "json"
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks that's work. But what about the name? I also tried to get the name but it does not work, why?

Comment: Hi @Mefisto_Fell I updated the answer, you need to navigate to the .name using some jquery functions; .parent() and .find(). I updated the answer.